# How do you write HTML and JS to a page with Firefox Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I can't figure out how to inject HTML and javascript onto a webpage with Firefox extensions.

This works with Chrome extension but does NOT work with Firefox. Notice I use chrome.extension.getURL which pulls in HTML and Javascript.

Here is my manifest - note I dont even use the background stuff

```js
{
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "js/background.js", "js/jquery.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "js/jquery.js", "js/chart-min.js", "js/chart-colors.js", "js/jquery-ui.min.js", "js/profiles/my_request.js", "js/options.js", "js/profiles/projects_builder.js", "js/profiles/board_builder.js", "js/profiles/my_api.js", "js/profiles/user_board_builder.js", "js/profiles/user_board.js","js/profiles/default_labels.js", "js/profiles/default_lists.js", "js/profiles/master_board.js", "js/profiles/projects.js",  "js/profiles/estimates.js", "js/profiles/new_todo_label.js","js/profiles/reports_dashboard.js",  "js/profiles/mutation_observer.js", "js/profiles/completion_chart.js", "js/profiles/cumulative_flow_chart.js"  ],
       "matches": [ "https://asana.com/*" ],
       "all_frames": true
    }],
  "permissions":[ "identity", "cookies", "storage", "activeTab", "https://asana.com/*"],
  "name": "Boards here",
  "short_name" : "boards",
  "version": "3.1.9.5",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons"   : { "48":  "images/logo_thicker.png"},
  "description": "html for website",
  "browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"images/logo_thicker.png",
    "default_popup":"html/popup.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [ "images/*",  "html/*" ]
}
```

Example for default lists -- default_lists.js utilizing my_request which is just a jquery ajax wrapper

```js
DefaultLists = (function() {
  function DefaultLists() {

     if (window.location.href.includes('#default_lists')) {
        this.show_form()
    }

   DefaultLists.prototype.show_form = function {
        my_request.ajax({
            url: chrome.extension.getURL("html/manage_default_lists.html"),
            type: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
              $('.panel.panel--project').remove()
              $('.panel.panel--perma').html(data)
            }
         });
    };
  }

  return DefaultLists;
})();
window.default_lists = new DefaultLists();
```

So now manage_default_lists.html looks something like

```js
<section style="position:relative;top:-50px;" class="message-board__content">
<bc-infinite-page page="1" reached-infinity="" direction="down" trigger="bottom">
  <table class="my_labels" data-infinite-page-container="">
      <tbody>
        <tr id="loading_lists" >
          <td>
            <span style="margin-left:280px;color:grey">Loading...</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <tr id="create_row" style="display:none">
          <td>
            <span class="">
              <input id="new_label_name" placeholder="List name" type="text" style="width:180px;font-size:15px;margin-left:42px;padding:5px;border-radius: 0.4rem;border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;" value="">
              <a style="margin-left:10px;float:right;margin-right:80px" class="cancel_new btn--small btn small" href="#">cancel</a>
              <input id="create_label" style="float:right;" type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn--small btn--primary primary small" data-behavior="loading_on_submit primary_submit" data-loading-text="saving…">
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </bc-infinite-page>     
</section>
</article>

  <script>
  $('#cancel_delete_label_button').on('click', function(event){
    $('#delete_label_modal').hide()
  });

  $('#cancel_force_lists_button').on('click', function(event){
    $('#force_lists_modal').hide()
  });

  $(document).off( "click", '.edit_label').on('click', '.edit_label', function(event) {
    td = $(this).parents('td')
    td.find('.show_row').hide()
    td.find('.edit_row').show()
    event.preventDefault()
  });

  $(document).off( "click", '.cancel_edit').on('click', '.cancel_edit', function(event) {
    td = $(this).parents('td')
    td.find('.show_row').show()
    td.find('.edit_row').hide()
    event.preventDefault()
  });

  $(document).off( "click", '.cancel_new').on('click', '.cancel_new', function(event) {
    // console.log('cancel')
    $('#create_row').hide()
    event.preventDefault()
  });

  $(document).off( "click", '#new_label_button').on('click', '#new_label_button', function(event) {
    $('#create_row').show()
    $('#new_label_name').val('')
    event.preventDefault()
  });

  $(document).off( "click", '#labels_article').on('click', '#labels_article', function(event) {
    // console.log(event.target.className)
    if (event.target.className != 'color-editor-bg'){
      $('.label-colors').hide();
    }
  });


</script>
```

Comment: Chrome extensions also forbid inline scripts by default in pages with `chrome-extension://` URL, meaning the popup or options or the background page. If it works for you then either you're not running this in an extension page context or you have already explicitly relaxed [content_security_policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). This is as much as can be deduced from the info you've provided in the question.

Comment: Hmm not sure how it’s working then which is scary. I’m not setting the content_security_policy. Is there a policy I can use in my manifest to make it work? What other info can I provide that would help? Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @wOxxOm Does the new added info help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding this HTML into the web page using your content script and web_accessible_resources. It's not related to the extension's CSP that forbids inline scripts in extension pages like the browser_action popup or the options page. In your case the CSP of the page applies to the stuff you add in it. The page may forbid inline scripts easily, sites often do that.

You can either rewrite the `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header of the page using webRequest API or **rework the code a bit**, the latter being a better solution not only because it's more focused but also because the result of rewriting an HTTP header is random when several extensions are doing it in the same HTTP request.

So let's rework the code:

- store the scripts separately
- fetch and inject via browser.tabs.executeScript
- run the injected code when we want it

The important change of behavior is that the code will be running in the content script's context, using content script's jQuery and variables. Previously your code was running in the page context so it was using jQuery and other variables of the page.

I'm using [Mozilla's `browser` WebExtension namespace polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/releases) and async/await syntax.

manifest.json:

```js
"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "browser-polyfill.min.js",
    "background.js"
  ]
},
"content_scripts": [{
  "js": [
    "browser-polyfill.min.js",
    "content.js"
  ],
  "matches": ["........."]
}],
```

directory structure:

- html/manage_default_lists.html
- html/manage_default_lists.js

Since executeScript can only be used in an extension page, not in a content script, we'll send a message to the background script with an instruction.

content.js:

```js
async function getResource(name) {
  const htmlUrl = browser.runtime.getURL(`html/${name}.html`);
  const [html, scriptId] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(htmlUrl).then(r => r.text()),
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({
      cmd: 'executeScript',
      path: `html/${name}.js`,
    }),
  ]);
  const js = window[scriptId];
  delete window[scriptId];
  return {html, js};
}

DefaultLists.prototype.show_form = async () => {
  const {html, js} = await getResource('manage_default_lists');
  $('.panel.panel--project').remove()
  $('.panel.panel--perma').html(html);
  js();
};
```

background.js:

```js
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender) => {
  if (!message) return;
  switch (message.cmd) {
    case 'executeScript': {
      const js = await (await fetch(browser.runtime.getURL(message.path))).text();
      const id = `js.${performance.now()}${Math.random()}`;
      await browser.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id, {
        // 0 at the end is to prevent executeScript from additionally returning
        // the function's code as a string, which we don't need 
        code: `window["${id}"] = () => { ${js} };0`,
        frameId: sender.frameId,
        matchAboutBlank: true,
        runAt: 'document_start',
      });
      return id;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I spent all last night moving the JS from the HTML file into a separate JS file. Then after dealing with a browser storage issue, I was able to get that JS to run with a content script. It was an improvement but still didn’t load when I needed to. I then was trying to think how I could programmatically include the JS instead of loading via the manifest and your answer looks correct. I’ll be able to test that out but I’m marking this answer as correct unless I run into an issue tomorrow. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate the explanation of everything!!

Comment: Man Ive spent hours and cant get it to work. I'm getting a "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource" error from the getResource sendMessage. Any idea why? Do I need to add a permissions? I have the directory in my web_accessible_resources.

Comment: It means the path is incorrect and it should be trivial to find out why in devtools: Open the background page devtools, the network panel, retry the action in your web page and see what's being fetched.

Comment: When I look at the background.js and console.log everything - the ID and JS variables print out what I expect. tt can read the file and the executescript runs. But I noticed whenever those browser.runtime.getURL or browser.tabs.executeScript runs, I get the networkerror from the content.js even though everything prints out great from the background.js. Weird right?

Comment: Use the network panel in devtools to view what's actually happening, don't guess. Both in the background page and in the content script.

Comment: I dont see anything in the network tabs, in fact the background doesnt have anything at all. Upon further inspection, firefox doesnt like it when you await for the browser.runtime.sendMessage for a return value.  If you call it without await it doesnt return the scriptId obviously but it doesnt give a network error. As soon as you await then it freaks out if you are doing any browser.runtime or browser.tabs functions. It looks like Firefox is prohibiting this on purpose. Does the code work for you?

Comment: This is a standard approach for such things and similar code works without problems. Use Chrome's devtools because it's infinitely superior for debugging extensions.

Comment: Also you can set breakpoints in devtools and debug the code to see what's actually happening. With Devtools debugger this should be resolved in a matter of seconds/minutes.

Comment: When I use Chrome I don't get a network error but I get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number at window[2553.8599999999860.05089676896034612] = () => { alert(1)
 };0

Comment: I can't win! haha

Comment: The id should start with a letter and use quotes, see the updated code.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the decimal and it worked too but I like the string better. The code works great in Chrome but Firefox blocks it. I dont think Firefox allows this.

Comment: There's nothing in this code for Firefox to block it. Use its [inconvenient] debugger to find out what's **actually** wrong, don't guess.

Comment: Sorry this thread is so long but I really appreciate your help. Apparently its the "await" in the background.js not the "browser.tabs" or "browser.runtime" that is causing the error. Does that mean anything to you? I'm new to await and async.

Comment: How would I know what the error is? See some tutorials about async/await, it's a super useful feature. In short you need to use await only inside an async function, just like it's done in my answer.

Comment: I got it all working now! To get it working I had to do add "https://*/" to the permissions. Is there a permission for this kind of behavior so I don't have open access to all websites?

Comment: It probably means your current pattern is incorrect e.g. it's too narrow or doesn't account for some server redirects. Check devtools network panel in the site's tab and see which URLs are requested. I guess `"https://*.asana.com/*"` might be what you need.